# MySQL Authentication failed to remote server

Tags: mysql

```
Authentication to host 'MY_DB_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'MY_APP_IP_ADDRESS' (using password: YES).
```

I have checked that I have full privileges for 'root'@'%'.

why is this happening?

**UPDATE:**
I can see that querying the db users shows on:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost'
```

it shows:

1. 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'root\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\' WITH GRANT OPTION'
2. 'GRANT PROXY ON \'\'@\'\' TO \'root\'@\'localhost\' WITH GRANT OPTION'

when querying the db:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%'
```

it shows only:
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'root\'@\'%\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\' WITH GRANT OPTION'

Is this related to what I am asking?

Comment: are you sure you have not tied root with an IP address?

Comment: Create the same user twice one with `user@'MY_DB_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS'` and the same user with `user@'%'` so you can connect from any host http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'root\'@\'%\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\' WITH GRANT OPTION'

Comment: @Mihai, I have done that. need i grant proxy to root@MY_DB_SERVER_IP as well?

Comment: To be frank I`m not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bind-address config in `my.cnf` file. It might be the case that mysql is only bound to specific ip's. If your security constraints allow it, comment out this line in `my.cnf` or change it appropriately.

If that doesn't help, try checking the `user` table in the `mysql` database and check if the grant statement was run correctly.